# SVN Update Crontab Linux

Tags: linux, svn, ssh, cron

I am trying to figure out how to run a SSH command via cron for linux.  The command I want to run is:

```
svn update /path/to/working/dir
```

Something like:

```
*/1 * * * * root ssh svn update /path/to/working/dir
```

Anyone know what I would need to do with the cron line?

EDIT: I don't need it to be SSH, just need to run svn update on the same server as cron to the working directory.

EDIT 2: What I was looking for was:

```
*/1 * * * * svn update /path/to/your/working/copy
```

I worded it incorrectly though, asking too specific about SSH, so I awarded the answer that talks about cron via SSH specifically, but if anyone wants to know how to do it locally, you don't need SSH.

Comment: Just to be sure, you really want to update once every minute? I can see a very unhappy repository.

Comment: Was just an example, but want to do it quite frequently as some people will be using the server for testing instead of locally.  Will it really cause a huge issue if it's not actually updating anything for most of the time?

Comment: Well, every time you try this, you are opening an connection to the SvN server - a connection that has to be maintained and closed, which eats server ressources. I would not do this per minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the host name (and also the username, unless you want to log in as root) to SSH:

```
*/1 * * * * root ssh user@hostname svn update /path/to/working/dir
```

Also see `ssh --help` for more information.

Note that you'd need to input your password with SSH, unless you've [setup your SSH](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) to be able to log in without password

Comment: How would you pass the password it?  Is that secure or do you recommend another way of running the svn update automatically?

Comment: _How would you pass the password to it?_ You can use generated keys. `man ssh-keygen` for more info. You need to run it for both server and client. It generates public and private keys in a `.ssh` directory. Add the public key to the `authorized_keys` in the server's `.ssh` directory.

Comment: This works great for remote, but is unnecessary if just needed for local.  I have posted the answer above for local.  I am awarding this answer though since I asked specifically about SSH and cron.

Answer (score 3):

You must compare the environment variables. I've wrote a simple bash script to do that for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
env
echo $PATH
type -a svn
cd /home/<username>
svn info
exit 0
```

And save it in /home//crontest.sh

Then you execute the code by hand and write the result into a file:

```
/home/<username>/crontest.sh > /home/<username>/hand_env
```

Then in your crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/<username/crontest.sh > /home/<username>/cron_env
```

After that you have two files, you will probably see that there are some differences between the environment variables.

The solution to the svn and cron problem is to set the environment variables in bash script of svn update to those obtained by hand it should look something like this (parts 2>/dev/null and exit 0 **ARE VERY IMPORTANT**):

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X$
export MAIL=/var/mail/root
export _=/usr/bin/env
export PWD=/home/tv
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export HOME=/home/tv
export SHLVL=2
export LOGNAME=root
#export LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
#export LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
export SHELL=/bin/bash
svn update https://localhost/svn /var/www/<dir> 2>/dev/null
exit 0
```

Write this script in for eg. /etc/init.d/skrypty/cron.sh
Then you just put in your crontab (i've done it as root)

```
* * * * * /etc/init.d/skrypty/cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue where I had edited crontab as `root` user. I have working copy under my home (`/home/myname/project`) directory and I did edit crontab as `myname` user and it worked.

`0 22 * * * bash /home/myname/svn.sh`

`svn.sh` has the following lines

`#!/bin/sh
svn up /home/myname/project`